# Set multiple options for "matches" in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to set multiple options for "matches" and then load a certain JS file?
I have this code:

```
  {
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name": "My First Extension",
        "description": "This is my first content-script extension",
        "version": "1.0",
        "content_scripts": [{
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "matches": "asdasd"
            "js": ["jquery.min.js", "content-script-1.js"]
        }],
        "browser_action": {
        },
        "permissions": [
            "activeTab"
        ]
    }
```

So like if "matches" is "asd", I want to do

```
"js": ["jquery.min.js", "content-script-1.js"]
```

and if "matches" is "dsa", I want to set "js" to

```
["jquery.min.js", "content-script-100.js"]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could just add another block to your content script:

```
 "content_scripts": [
       {
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "matches": "asd"
        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "content-script-1.js"]
       },
        {
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "matches": "dsa"
        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "content-script-100.js"]
       }

]
```

Another option is to use [executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) - then you could choose when to inject your js file into the page.

Comment: Thanks! executeScript is not ideal for my needs because I want it to happen automatically but thanks for the tip :) But when doing that code, does it then check if the page matches "asd" and if it does not, it moves to the next block of code? So it sort of works like an if statement or..

Comment: It's simple - when you are in the page you write under matches the script you write there inject . If you are in another page so it's just not inject so if you want you could look about this with if statement .